# How to force ASP.NET MVC to read .cshtml files as UTF-8?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, utf-8

When rendering a view, I encounter a problem with encoding, i.e. unicode characters are displayed incorrectly.

According to [an answer to an unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/663980/240613):

> If you experience encoding problems with the output, try saving your view .aspx files as 'Unicode UTF-8 with signature'.

Indeed, my views were saved as *UTF-8 without signature*; saving them as *UTF-8 with signature* solves the problem.

Is there a way to specify to ASP.NET MVC that it should use UTF-8 every time, in order to be able to use UTF-8 without signature for the newly stored views?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />
</system.web>
```

Don't forget to save your source file in UTF-8 as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe encoding is not the responsibility of MVC, rather IIS. Do you have this line in your web.config?

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Comment: The problem occurs before IIS, since the encoding is already wrong in the HTML string I generate from the view.