# Remove ï»¿ from page-content in mvc razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, byte-order-mark

I can see ï»¿ characters on top of my razor page inside the page-content div. I was not able to trace that down and remove it.
can anyone help me to remove it?

Comment: I also faced this issue when I tried to use currency format in my razor from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071273/currency-formatting Is there any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's [Byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark%20the%20representation) for the UTF-8 BOM in ISO-8859-1.
Try to fix encoding in your razor pages.

Comment: Hi Dima,  Can you suggest how to encode in razor view

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and was able to remove those symbols by removing the blank row at the top of my View.

Example:

```
[blank row here] --> remove this
@model RecLeagueBlog.Models.UserRoleViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "EditUser";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DashboardLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to call static html page using below code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var staticPageToRender = new FilePathResult("~/uploads/test.html", "text/html");
        return staticPageToRender;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is from:
[How do I make Razor read UTF-8 files without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431985/how-do-i-make-razor-read-utf-8-files-without-bom)

Simply add this to your web.config

```
<system.web>
   <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" />
</system.web>
```

The BOM symbols are now gone.