# how to fix: website pages show question marks in online but not in localhost(offline)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, utf-8

i have website and some letters shows like `�` that but only in online and not in `localhost`, the site is in asp.net-MVC, i use visual studio 2017, the content is stored in database sql server,

i  try `meta charset=utf-8` tag, with notepad++ save cshtml in utf-8 with bom, 
 but they didn't help,

Comment: what happens if you try utf-16?

Comment: i try but didn't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force ASP.NET MVC to read .cshtml files as UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117930/how-to-force-asp-net-mvc-to-read-cshtml-files-as-utf-8)