# Resources file for AngularJS does not provided correct encoded string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have resources.json file which looks like:

```
...
{
  "MyStatus": "Beëindigd"
},
...
```

I display in a table that string

```
<td data-i18n="MyStatus"></td>
```

When app loads, the resource file downloaded from server looks like:

```
{"MyStatus":"BeA«indigd"}
```

And response header (seems to have charset utf-8):

[image]

How to display `Beëindigd` instead of `BeA«indigd` ?

What should do here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting charset in header response does not ensure the data source is properly encoded as UTF-8.

First, open your `resources.json` file in an editor like VSCode or Sublime and check it's encoded in UTF-8 and not another charset.

Then, check your source code files on server side are also encoded as UTF-8.

Finally, if you're using Java to serve your API, check that the JVM is started with the UTF-8 encoding and not the system default charset which is sometimes different.
Use `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to do this.

Comment: I used asp.net mvc with angularjs

Comment: I don't know asp.net but it seems the encoding can be set this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/22319145/7557538